# Oracle Trigger Updating a field on an Insert or an Update

Tags: oracle, triggers

For some reason I'm running a blank on how to go about doing something like this.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
UserID   |  Name   |  DateAdded   |   LastUpated
--------------------------------------------------
1        | James Q | 1/1/2009     |
```

If I insert or update record the lastupdated field should be updated the sysdate.
How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   :new.LastUpdated := sysdate;
END;
```

Try that. I did not have a oracle server at hand, but I hope I got the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

create or replace trigger mytable_bi
before insert on mytable
for each row
begin

:NEW.lastupdated := sysdate();

end;

create or replace trigger mytable_bu
before update on mytable
for each row
begin

:NEW.lastupdated := sysdate();

end;